# What is a formal programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, formal-languages

What does it mean that a programming language is a formal programming language? And which languages are formal programming languages? And which are informal programming languages?

I haven't found a good explanation yet.

Comment: It depends how they dress. :-)

Comment: This is only the 7th question ever to be tagged as formal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/formal-languages - so whatever it is (or isn't) it isn't Facebook.  Or Twitter.

Comment: Maybe you mean by "formal", you mean Turing-complete?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every programming language is a formal language, so that it does not make much sense to me to speak of a “formal programming language.” (Or does somebody know an informal programming language?)

Formal language is a language with mathematically precise construction rules. Or, more precisely, it’s a set of words over some alphabet. For example, if you take alphabet consisting of the letters `a`, `b` and `c`, a formal language over this alphabet could be a set {`a`, `aa`, `aba`, `ca`}. Of course such a language would not be very useful – the point is that with a decent set of construction rules you can create a language such as C or PostScript.

As for the “construction rules,” they could be a formal grammar (see grammar for [CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/grammar.html)), a regular expression (see this [gorgeous regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) for e-mail addresses as defined by RFC 822), an automaton or a general algorithm.

---

If you feel you don’t understand the thing a tiny bit more, do not despair, for this is not a very good explanation :-) There’s a lot of thinking behind the concept of formal languages. I’d suggest that you try and digest the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) and look for more tutorials and books. It’s fun and you will learn a lot about the background of compilers, regular expressions, Turing machines and other wonders of digital mankind.

Comment: “Informal programming” seems like a contradiction to me, but you’re right, I guess that pseudocode could be considered an informal programming language. (For sufficiently vague interpretations of “programming.”)

Comment: I have heard people talk about formal programming language, so I just thought there had to something called an informal programming language to. But I guess not. Pseudocode, as mentioned, maybe the closest one. Thanks

Comment: In the world of formal languages, the word `word` means any valid string. Thus a formal language `word` is any valid `statement` or `expression` which may containing spaces and other delimiters.

Comment: From what I understand formal is a programming style, not a language. It is a way to mathematically prove every line - basically self-validating. e.g. you must be able to prove that a specific line of code will only do what it's supposed to regardless of any other conditions (memory errors, buffer overflows, etc). An informal programming accounts for a vast majority - this relies on testing the code for function. i.e. if it does what it's supposed to - it's good.

Answer (score 2):

Formal means well defined. Every programming language that can be used to define executable programs has to be well defined so that machines can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "formal language" it's a formal method of programming: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods). It needn't be a specific language but rather the way you write specification and verify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thats an extract from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)

"John C. Reynolds emphasizes that formal specification languages are just as much programming languages as are the languages intended for execution. He also argues that textual and even graphical input formats that affect the behavior of a computer are programming languages, despite the fact they are commonly not Turing-complete, and remarks that ignorance of programming language concepts is the reason for many flaws in input formats"

Comment: Formal specification languages != formal languages.

Comment: See all the extract pls "He also argues that textual and even graphical input formats that affect the behavior of a computer are programming languages"

Answer (score 0):

Formal languages are languages which only consider about the well-formedness nothing else. That means the sufficient and necessary condition is to adhere to its rules.
An example rule:

For eg. If we define language for decimal numbers as {x | finite set of digits without leading zeroes}. (simply put, decimals means a sequence of digits.)

So if the language containing above rule to be formal,it should adhere adhere to the given rule.

But in practical usage, if the language treats 001 as a decimal number we can conclude the programming language is not formal, Since its not exactly according to the rule set it defines.

Normally language parsers checks these rules.
So a formal language should always be well-formed (following its own rules strictly)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are relating to the definition of formal programming language according to Computer Science. However, this answer is relating to the definition of formal programming language according to Social (wannabe) Science.

According to `dictionary.com`, one of the definitions for 'formal' is `being in accordance with the usual requirements, customs, etc.; conventional`.

A formal programming language is a programming language which is widely used and accepted by the person talking about it. Therefore, it is domain and conversation specific. Perhaps a better way of wording is 'popular', 
traditional', 'mainstream' or 'widely-accepted' programming language. For example, in business and industry this refers to `SQL`, `Java`, `C#`, `C++`, `Python` and `PHP`.

Examples of informal programming languages are `SPL` (the Shakespeare Programming Language), `FORTRAN` and `CoffeeScript`. It is more accurate to say that one language is more conventional and thus formal than another than it is to say that one language is formal and another is informal.
After all, `Lisp` would be a very informal programming language for making a website, but a very formal programming language for developing Artificial Intelligence research.